# SQLite wrapper in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sqlite

I have an iPhone app that stores information to a SQLite database. It works splendid on my phone as well as my brothers. Stuff get's written to it and it can read from it. However, when running it on other people's phone's, it just crashes. Why?

I am using Matteo Bertozzi's SQLite wrapper (put files in the classes folder and linked to them in my .h like this: `#import "Sqlite.h"`)

I have also imported the `libsqlite3.dylib` to my project.

Declared my SQLite database like this in my .h as well: `Sqlite *database;`

Set up my database like this:

```
if (database == nil) {
// Set up database connection
NSString *myDBTwo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flashpics.db"];
database = [[Sqlite alloc] init];
[database open:myDBTwo];
}
```

And call a query like this (none of my variables are nil) :

```
[database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO images (id, thumbnail, album, caption) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", photoID, thumbnailLocation, photoAlbumID, photoCaption];
```

However it crashes on my friend's phone and returns `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to read it.. Nothing happens when you try to write to it.

Please help!
Thanks

PS: Here's the link to the wrapper: http://th30z.blogspot.com/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper_8445.html

**Edit #1:** Here's some of the errors I get when loading the app. Maybe this is causing it? Or it's not linking to the correct library?

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
```

And here's what I get when I do the action that makes it crash.

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

Comment: Try www.github.com/pmurphyjam/DBExample It's an Xcode project that uses SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to write to the resources folder in your app bundle, which is read only on a non-jailbroken system, due to safety/security reasons, you have to create the database in the documents folder, so you change your code to this...

EDIT: SORRY I pasted the WRONG code, here is the fixed version.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *myDBTwo = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flashpics.db"];
```

Comment: My .db file is in my "Other Sourced" folder. Should I move it to my documents folder? Will that do anything?

Comment: @phpnerd211 The folder it is stored in initially in xcode(your computer) does not matter. However, for the file to be writable you will have to copy it over to the documents folder for your app(in the iphone), using separate code as part of the applications first launch routine.

Answer (score 1):

RTS is right, you have to copy it over to the Documents directory (or someplace similar) that is writable.

The reason it worked on your devices? If I had to guess I'd say you're both jailbroken and that notion of a code-signed bundle that cannot be modified isn't really enforced.