# iPhone app rejected: What do I do now?

Tags: ios, ios4

My iPhone app was just rejected today - sad day. I was looking forward to the release of it after 2 months of development and counting.

I tested the snot out of it for crashes and I couldn't crash it. However apple experienced a unknown crash. I haven't been able to get an answer from anyone what is the issue and I am beginning to move on to a different app - I've had too much errors with this one.

- Basically it's working on my brother and I's phone (both jailbroken iPhones on iOS 4.2.1).
- The app is built for iOS 4.2.1
- Doesn't work on any other phone tested (crashes because can't write to database) Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785183/sqlite-wrapper-in-ios).

What do I do next? Why is it only working on select phones? Is this a coincidence?

Thanks
Coulton

Comment: Don't they give you specific steps to reproduce the bugs or a crash log or something along these lines?

Comment: You said that it *doesn't* work on any other phone tested, and yet you're asking why it got rejected?

Comment: You need to try it on a non-jailbroken iPhone to make sure the crash is not occuring on a vanilla system.

Comment: Yes, however it works just fine on my phone (iOS 4.2.1 iPhone 3G) and their phone was iOS 4.3.2 on a iPhone 4 (which i do not have and don't have access to).

Comment: You can also try submitting it to Cydia--after all, you've tested it on a jailbroken device and it worked.

Comment: @phpnerd211--how's the iPhone simulator -- is it working on it?

Comment: @phpnerd211, that's fine and dandy that it works on your phone, but you're probably not selling your phone, now are you? Make it work out of the box on a typical user's phone.

Comment: @dawebber Yes, it does. iOS 4.2.1 simulator.

Comment: @Stargazer712: No, I need help trying ti figure out how to fix it. Please see the link to my other post... I have figured out that's my problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: ...so the entire point of this question is to direct attention to another question?

Comment: @phpnerd211--if @StarGazer712 is right, you are going to get downvoted. I don't believe SO condones this sort of approach

Comment: @dawebber: I really am sorry, but I am really desperate. This post made me get a response that worked.

Comment: @phpnerd211--I'm glad it worked for you. So, basically the problem was that in the jailbroken device you had access to read/write to and from pretty much anywhere on the filesystem, which is why your jailbroken device worked. My suggestion above to post to Cydia may not be that bad of an idea :)

Comment: @dawebber: Yeah, correct! I am going to submit to the app store and Cydia at the same time. Even if I get rejected to the app store, I will most likely get accepted into the Cydia store!

Comment: Y don't you just write it to another writable folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey .. are you copying the database into the documents directory? you can't write in the resource folder.. are you aware of this thing?

Comment: Yes, in my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I check if the file exists in my DOCUMENTS directory. If it doesn't, I copy my database file to it and every time a reference my database or write to it, I use the version in the DOCUMENTS folder.